# How do I make a View 50% transparent?

Tags: android, colors, view, transparent

I have followed the article [Layout Tricks: Using ViewStubs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html) to set a View on top of another. I used `FrameLayout` as the root element containing one `MapView` and a `ViewStub`. At the place for `ViewStub` I later opened a `LinearLayout` with the `android:background` set to a color with color value `<color name="blue_opaque">#f005</color>`.

The position for the `LinearLayout` seem to be right, it sits on top and it has a blue background but it is not transparent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color hex code is built like this. `#ARGB` or for a more fine grained control `#AARRGGBB` which means AlphaRedGreenBlue. You set your alpha to 100% be opaque. Try `#6005`.